# How to add minutes in C

Tags: c

I have a function to add any minutes to a date time in C using struct tm and maketime. the function takes in date time in string and minutes in integer then add the minutes to the date time then return a string.

```
char *addMinutes(char *dateTime, int mins)
{
    /* Intput & Output: YYYYMMDDHHMM */
    char year[5];
    char month[3];
    char day[3];
    char HH[3];
    char MM[3];
    char newDateTime[13];
    struct tm t;

    STRMCPY(year,   dateTime,    4);
    STRMCPY(month, &dateTime[4], 2);
    STRMCPY(day,   &dateTime[6], 2);
    STRMCPY(HH,    &dateTime[8], 2);
    STRMCPY(MM,    &dateTime[10],2);

    printf("input %s %s %s %s %s\n",year,month,day,HH,MM);
    t.tm_year = atoi(year);
    t.tm_mon = atoi(month)-1;
    t.tm_mday = atoi(day);
    t.tm_hour = atoi(HH);
    t.tm_min = atoi(MM)+mins;

    printf("input %d %d %d %d %d\n",t.tm_year,t.tm_mon,t.tm_mday,t.tm_hour,t.tm_min);

    mktime(&t);
    printf("input %d %d %d %d %d\n",t.tm_year,t.tm_mon,t.tm_mday,t.tm_hour,t.tm_min);

    sprintf(newDateTime, "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d", t.tm_year, t.tm_mon,
                            t.tm_mday,t.tm_hour,t.tm_min);

    return newDateTime;
}
```

Below is my result if i call above function 
strcpy(atb30, addMinutes("201812120431",30));

```
input 2018 12 12 04 31
input 2018 11 12 4 61
input 2018 11 12 5 41
atb 201811120541
```

I don't understand why my program is not working.
And what's the correct way to write a addMinutes function using C.

Comment: You should check one of the functions that calls a ptr to a tm object. It normalizes all the values in the tm obj. That's the easy way to do this.

Comment: `tm_year` is "years since 1900".  You need to subtract 1900 from the full year when writing it, and add 1900 when reading it.  Note also your function is returning a pointer to a value in the function's local stack.  Using that pointer after your function returns is undefined behavior.

Comment: Hi paddy, thanks i noted the warning: `warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr] return newDateTime;`  when i compile the program. Would like to know how can i avoid this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues

**Wrong epoch**

The `.tm_year` member is from 1900. [@paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739337/how-to-add-minutes-in-c/54739831#comment96261290_54739337)

```
// t.tm_year = atoi(year);
t.tm_year = atoi(year) - 1900;
```

**Check for success**

```
// mktime(&t);
if (mktime(&t) == -1) {
  puts("Failed conversion");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**Incomplete assignment**

OP's code does not assign the other members of `t`, leading to questionable result.  Instead, completely assign `t` and use `-1` for the `.tm_isdst` if you do  not know the daylight setting for the date.

```
// struct tm t;
struct tm t = { 0 };

t.tm_isdst = -1; // add
t.tm_year = atoi(year)  - 1900;
t.tm_mon = atoi(month) - 1;
t.tm_mday = atoi(day);
t.tm_hour = atoi(HH);
t.tm_min = atoi(MM) + mins;
if (mktime(&t) == -1) {
  puts("Failed conversion");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**Return of invalid pointer**

`return newDateTime;` attempts to return a pointer to a local array.  This is *undefined behavior*.  Code needs a new approach.  Recommend passing into the function allocation to store the new `newDateTime`.

**Stingy buffer size**

`char newDateTime[13];` is borderline sufficient.  What happens should the year exceed 4 characters?

```
// char newDateTime[13];
// sprintf(newDateTime, "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d", 
//     t.tm_year, t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday,t.tm_hour,t.tm_min);
char newDateTime[13 * 2];
snprintf(newDateTime, sizeof newDateTime, "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d", 
     t.tm_year + 1900, t.tm_mon + 1, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min);
```

Also research `strftime()`.

Comment: Thanks chux i have updated my code according to your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel and accept a string, which you have to parse. Instead take in a pointer to `struct tm`. This way, "somebody else" can take care of handling string inputs.

```
struct tm *addMinutes(const struct tm *time, int nMin)
{
    time_t equivalent = mktime(time);
    equivalent += (nMin*60);

    return localtime(&equivalent);
}
```

Comment: I am reading a date time from a flat file i need to convert it to struct tm type i use make time to convert a string to struct tm the time value seems will be changed by the program.

Comment: @XiamengLi Consider `strftime` or `asctime` (look em up in the man pages). Converting date strings into integers is extremely complicated and you don't need to do it

Comment: `equivalent += (nMin*60);` assumes `time_t` is a count of seconds.  Common, yet not specified by C.  There is no need for this assumption, just copy `time` and add `nMin` to its `.tm_min`, then call `mktime()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to tp, the `tm_min` parameter only takes integers from 0 to 59. Consider processing your input with some if/while statements to ensure the hour and minute are stored correctly before calling `mktime(&t);`

Comment: "the tm_min parameter only takes integers from 0 to 59" --> No.  C does dot require that.  All `int` values are valid for `.tm_min` with `gmtime()`.  "... and the original values of the other components are not restricted to the ranges indicated above."  C11 §7.26.2.3 2

Answer (score 0):

After read all the replies i updated my code to below.

```
void addMinutes(char *dateTime, int mins,char *newDateTime)
{
    /* Intput & Output: YYYYMMDDHHMM */
char year[5];
char month[3];
char day[3];
char HH[3];
char MM[3];
struct tm *info;

STRMCPY(year,   dateTime,    4);
STRMCPY(month, &dateTime[4], 2);
STRMCPY(day,   &dateTime[6], 2);
STRMCPY(HH,    &dateTime[8], 2);
STRMCPY(MM,    &dateTime[10],2);

struct tm t = { 0 };
t.tm_isdst = -1;
t.tm_year = atoi(year)-1900;
t.tm_mon = atoi(month)-1;
t.tm_mday = atoi(day);
t.tm_hour = atoi(HH);
t.tm_min = atoi(MM)+mins;
t.tm_sec = 0;

if (mktime(&t) == -1) {
    printf("Failed conversion\n");
    exit(-1);
}
    time_t equivalent = mktime(&t);
    strftime(newDateTime,80,"%Y%m%d%H%M", localtime(&equivalent));  
}
```